# Destroying connection when $destroy in SignalR

Tags: angularjs, typescript, signalr

I have a page running SignalR, Angular, and Typescript. When the current `$scope` gets destroyed (like a page change), I try to disconnect the client from the SignalR server:

**Controller.ts**

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", () => Service.Disconnect());
```

My frontend service then has this function:

**Service.ts**

```
public Disconnect() {
    this.hub.disconnect();
}
```

So when I change the page, the client disconnects from the hub. This works perfectly, as I can see in the console:

> SignalR: Stopping connection.
>
> SignalR: Closing the Websocket.
>
> SignalR: Fired ajax abort async = true.
>
> SignalR: Stopping the monitoring of the keep alive.

Works perfectly. However, when I then load a new state and my connection gets set again, the old connection is somehow "kept", because it then tries to connect twice. If I then go to a different page and back again, it tries to connect 3 times.

**EDIT**

It seems like the `stateChanged` gets called multiple times. Multiple times being the amount of times the connection setup has been called. Hmm, I wonder why it does that, when I disconnect the client from the hub. Fixed it with a simple `if already connected` variable I set the first time connecting, but it's not really good.

Is there a proper way to disconnect the client? Should the server/backend hub handle the disconnection as well? Should I do anything else than disconnect the client from the hub, when the `$scope` is destroyed?

Comment: did you find a proper for of disconnecting hub . I'm facing the same issue in Ionic 2 with signalr

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? I am experiencing exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using this.hub.stop();

Comment: `hub.stop is not a function` is what I'm getting. Instead of calling `this.hub.disconnect()`, I am calling `this.hub.stop()`.

Comment: With this.hub.stop() it is running?

Comment: Yes, the hub is running. `hub` does not contain a method called `stop`. It contains these: http://i.imgur.com/k2NC8eK.png (most of them being my registered functions).

Comment: Can you show your source? You are not using the generated proxy?

Comment: Well, I am using an angular wrapper to create the hub. https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-signalr-hub - Basically turned that into Typescript, but it's the same thing really. My `this.hub` is the hub from that wrapper's `var hub = new Hub('employee', {`

Comment: I think it's the most important info that you use this wrapper!

Comment: Sure it is, but the hub is still the same. Once compiled, it's all just Javascript anyways.